# Dynamically return values for PHP contact form

Tags: php, html

I've got a basic PHP contact form and have it `process.php` file that checks the content of the form. I have the form working correctly but i want to populate the contents of my `returnstatus` div with `$errors` without fully refreshing the page. I'm sure this is a simple task but i'm not sure how to go about it. Here is my code:

**Contact Form**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
    <body>

        <div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">
            <h1>Get In Touch!</h1>
            <img id="stamp" src="images/stamp.png" height="128" width="128" alt="Stamp"/>
            <h2>
                Please provide as much information as possible for me to help you with your enquiry
            </h2>
            <div id="returnstatus">

            </div>  
            <form method="post" action="process2.php">
                <label for="name">Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Joe Bloggs" required="required" /> 

                <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="joebloggs@example.com" required="required" /> 

                <label for="message">Message: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 characters" required="required" data-minlength="20"></textarea>  

                <input type="text" name="check" class="check" />
                <span id="loading"></span>  
                <input type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit-button" />  
                <p id="req-field-desc"><span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field</p> 
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
<html>
```

**process2.php**

```
<?php   

$name       = check_input($_POST['name']);
$email      = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message    = check_input($_POST['message']);

$errors = "";
if (empty($name)){
    $errors .= "Please fill out the first name field <br/> ";
}
if (empty($email)){
    $errors .= "Please fill out the email field <br/> ";
} else {
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
        $errors .= 'The email address you entered does not appear to be valid<br />';
    }
}
if (strlen($message) < 21){
    $errors .= "Your message must be at least 20 characters";
}

if ($errors != "") {
    echo "<b>Message not sent</b><br/>";
    echo $errors;
} else {
    $errors = "<p>Thank you, $name, for your message.</p><p>I'll get back to you as soon as possible!</p>";
    echo $errors;
//send email if all is ok 
if ($_POST['check'] == '') {        //check to see if the hidden input entry is empty
    $headers = "From: {$email}" . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

    $emailbody = "<p>You have recieved a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p> 
                                <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p> 
                                <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p> 
                                <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>";
    mail("xxxxx@gmail.com","New Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers);  
    }
}  

function check_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: "without fully refreshing the page" - Do you mean you want the entire operation to happen as an AJAX call?  Or that you want _some_ behavior to happen client-side (checking for errors) and then refresh the whole page when the form is "correct"?

Comment: You have to use AJAX or JavaScript check.

Comment: Yes, i had a feeling i'd have to use Ajax, but i don't know how to pass the value from the php file to the contact form page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is to send an AJAX request. Learn more at [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`Request.HTML` in MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML). The `handleSuccess` methods below inject the HTML output from `process2.php` into `returnstatus`.

**[mootools](/questions/tagged/mootools) 1.4.5 Example**

```
(function(){
    var form = $$('#contact-form form')[0];
    var returnStatus = $('returnstatus');
    var handleSuccess = function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript) {
        returnStatus.set('html', responseHTML);
    };
    form.addEvent('submit', function() {
        new Request.HTML({
            url: form.get('action'), 
            onSuccess: handleSuccess
        }).post(form);
        return false;
    });
})();
```

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) 1.7.2 Example**

```
(function(){
    var form = $('#contact-form form');
    var returnStatus = $('#returnstatus');
    var handleSuccess = function(data) {
        returnStatus.html(data);
    };
    form.submit(function() {
        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), handleSuccess, 'html');
        return false;
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send AJAX request, using jQuery library you can **Serialize** the form data and send a $.post to the process2.php